# Error message "The method withTagName(String) is undefined for the type RelativeLocators" displayed at compile time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

At compile time I am receiving an error "The method withTagName(String) is undefined for the type RelativeLocators" while running the below program in eclipse even though the selenium version is "selenium-java-4.0.0-beta-4" and another error "The import org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName cannot be resolved" is displayed on the 5th import statement

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName;

public class RelativeLocators {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("rahulshettyacadmy.com/angularpractice");
        WebElement editbox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[name='name']"));
        driver.findElement(withTagName("input").above(editbox).getText());
        WebElement dobleabel = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[for='dateofbirth']"));
        driver.findElement(withTagName("input").below(dobleabel)).sendKeys("02/02/1993");
        WebElement iceCreams = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='Check me out if you Love IceCreams!']"));
        driver.findElement(withTagName("input").toLeftOf(iceCreams)).click();
        WebElement radiobutton = driver.findElement(By.id("inlineRadio1']"));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(withTagName("input").toRightOf(radiobutton)).getText());
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the error log?

Answer (score 0):

You have getTagName method in the Selenium plugin, but not withTagName...

Comment: "withTagName" is a new functionality that comes with selenium 4. Have a look at this https://blog.testproject.io/2020/07/13/selenium-4-relative-locators/