# Error message "The method withTagName(String) is undefined for type RelativeLocator" - Selenium 4 java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium4

When compiled within Eclipse IDE have an error "The method withTagName(String) is undefined for the type RelativeLocators" while running the test in Selenium-java 4.1.0.
[image: Current error]

I have followed the post on [Error message "The method withTagName(String) is undefined for the type RelativeLocators" displayed at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68834912/error-message-the-method-withtagnamestring-is-undefined-for-the-type-relative)
to import static org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.*; [image: method used]

Here are the details of selenium version.[image: Pom xml selenium version]

Comment: Hi there, you can enhance the quality of your question by replacing screenshots with text. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

May be the IDE is not importing the package completely try to import the below separately and check.

```
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName;
```